# script for sum of numbers in file which are written without space with text and special characters

Tags: python, bash, perl

Lets say a file has

```
abc[1:0]
2 abc
abc 3
[1:0] abc
```

I have a huge file with this . Now if i want to sum all the numbers like the below.

Note that numbers outside the bracket should not be calculated.

```
1+1+numberoflines
```

in this case 1+1+4 =6

How do i do it?

I tried number of approaches like

```
perl -nle '$sum+=$_} END { print $sum' test1.txt
```

or

```
n=$1
sum=0
sd=0
while [ $n -gt 0 ]
do
    sd=`expr $n % 10`
    sum=`expr $sum + $sd`
    n=`expr $n / 10`
done
echo  "Sum of digit for numner is $sum"
```

But none of them is taking the numbers without spaces.

Note that abc is just an example. It could be any random text along with numbers

Comment: So you want the output to be 11?  Like `1+2+3+1+4`?

Comment: sorry i misphrased the sentences. it should be 1 +1 + 4 =6. No number outside bracket should be calculated

Comment: What if you have a like like`def[5:7]` -- how does that contribute to the sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as described:

```
echo 'abc[1:0]
2 abc
abc 3
[1:0] abc' | perl -lnE 'while (/\[([^]]*)\]/g) { 
                            $s=$1;
                            while ($s=~/\b(\d+)\b/g) {
                                $sum+=$1;
                            }
                        }   
                        END {
                        say $sum+$.
                        }
'
```

Prints `6`

To understand it, insert some `say`s at appropriate places:

```
echo 'abc[1:0]
2 abc
abc 3
[1:0] abc' | perl -lnE 'while (/\[([^]]*)\]/g) { 
                            $s=$1;
                            say $s;
                            while ($s=~/\b(\d+)\b/g) {
                                say $1;
                                $sum+=$1;
                            }
                        }   
                        END {
                        say $.;
                        say $sum+$.
                        }
'
1:0      first bracketed group from /\[([^]]*)\]/g
1        digits within from $s=~/\b(\d+)\b/g
0
1:0
1
0
4        line count from $.
6        $sum + line count
```

For a Python solution, you can use the same regex and do:

```
import re 

total=0
with open(fn) as f:        # 'fn' is the path to your file
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if m:=re.findall(r'\[([^]]*)\]', line): 
            for e in m:
                total+=sum(map(int, re.findall(r'\b(\d+)\b', e)))
                
print(total+i)
```

There are limitations here with this regex: It will not handle unbalanced or nested brackets. That is a more complicated regex.

Python note:

The `:=` in `if m:=re.findall(r'\[([^]]*)\]', line):` is Python 3.9 only.
Break into two statements for earlier Python versions:

```
m=re.findall(r'\[([^]]*)\]', line)
if m:
    ...
```

Comment: This gives a syntax error   File "tt.py", line 8
    if m:=re.findall(r'\[([^]]*)\]', line):
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
As far as your first example, the text abc is just an example. It could be any random text.

Comment: `if m:=re.findall(r'[([^]]*)]', line):` requires Python 3.9. If you have an earlier Python, break that into two different statements: `m=re.findall(r'[([^]]*)]', line); if m: ...`

Comment: I corrected the errors but it gives wrong value

Comment: It works with the example you gave. If it gives the wrong value, there is something about your fie that is different than your example.

Comment: What is `if i == re.findall(r'[([^]]*)]', line)`? `i` is the line count and will never be equal to a list returned by `re.findall`

Comment: ignore my previous paste. I reverted back to m. Example is 
START
1 sdgsdfg
2 sgdgsdg //  No Change
 [3:0]//d gdfhhfgh
//dfbdfgdfg
//dgdfghdfsdf
#kgjfdkjg
// dfghsdfhf
    //   fhsg
   //   dfhfghfgh

END

Comment: One more suggestion i want as a follow up to this . Suppose the bracket has 2 numbers instead of 0 i.e. [4:1] . And what i need is (4-1)+1 how do i do it?

Comment: Why the `-1` inside the brackets and why the `+1` outside?

Comment: minus 1` as 1 is from` [4:1] +1` as the total width will be one added.

Comment: plus 1 is not required since we are counting number of lines.

Comment: This really sounds like it should be a new question vs trying to figure it out in comments. Since you have a skeleton, start with that. With specific issues, come back with another question.

Answer (score 0):

Using grep and sed, the following is:

```
echo $(( $(grep -o '\[.\+\]' test1.txt | sed -e 's/[^0-9]\+/\+/g' -e 's/^\+//g' ; cat test1.txt | wc -l) ))
```

1. Extract lines with a bracket.
2. Replace non-numbers with +.
3. Get the number of lines in the file.
4. Calculate as an arithmetic expression.

If brackets appear multiple times in a line, using sed instead of grep.

```
echo $(( $(sed -n -e '{s/.*\(\[.\+\]\).*/\1/g;T;p}' test1.txt | sed -e 's/[^0-9]\+/\+/g' -e 's/^\+//g'; cat test1.txt | wc -l) ))
```

Comment: echo $(($(grep -o '\[.\+\]' test1.txt | sed -z -e 's/[^0-9]\+/\+/g' ; cat test1.txt | wc -l) ))
Illegal variable name.

Comment: I think the command is correct. It works fine in my bash. Do you use bash?

Comment: it says invalid for -z